# Author's Name Of A Book On Bill Maher's Shelf

Tags: climate-change, climate, climatology, reference-request, literature-request

Could any of you, please, tell me who is the author of this book on Bill Maher's shelf? The book name is "Climate Science" and the cover color seems to be green. I looked for it on the Amazon website to no avail.

[image]

I appreciate your help.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see it in [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22climate+science%22&tbm=bks) either.

Comment: I would have put a bounty on this if it were still open; it would be fun to know if Bill Maher uses fake books! ;-) Seriously though, can't this clear, well-written and specific question about a specific resource on climate change be on-topic? Just this once? After all it was *on TV!*